# is it possible to get jquery intellisense when working with just one HTML

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I am trying to develop small  plain HTML page where I have referenced jquery and "my own javascript file" in head section. In the HTML page I have a button when users click button I would like to write code to send jquery ajax request in"my own javascript file" when user clicks button. I was wondering if there is anyway for me to get jquery intellisense enabled in "my own javascript file". Right now I am using visual studio 2015. I know VS2015 have intellisense when we have some kind of project or solution but since this a just one single HTML page is there anyway for me to get intellisense enabled in "my own javscript file" ? I am ok if I have to look for other IDE other than VS.

Comment: "Resharper", it can give you intellisense mark

Comment: is there any free tool. I think resharper we need to buy?